# Fixed-radius range search in non-Euclidean space

Tags: data-mining, clustering, bigdata, algorithms

I'm trying to find an indexing data structure most suitable for my **metric space**:

- set of IP network related data (IP addresses, ports, TCP flags, ...),
- distance function is continuous, non-Euclidean but satisfies non-negativity, symmetry and triangle inequality,

with respect to the **fixed-radius range query** performance. I want to use it for a clustering algorithm (DBSCAN or similar) on a data sets with millions of elements. So far I have studied:

- ball trees/VPT,
- MVPT,
- GHT, GNAT,
- AESA/LAESA,
- cover trees,

and basically all other methods from [Searching in metric spaces](http://www.academia.edu/download/44050685/p273-chavez.pdf) survey, but all mentioned are suited for varying-radius queries. Many related SO answers advise [Locality-sensitive hashing (LSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) as a current trend, but I didn't find any clear information whether it exploits the advantage of fixed-range and whether it is usable for non-Euclidean metrics. Any advices/references?

Comment: Try some of the indexes in ELKI to see what works best for your distance function...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse In ELKI there are only cover trees and M-trees metrical indexes. Others (including LSH) can be used with certain subset of distance functions only.

Comment: Yes, LSH etc. need specializations for every distance function. So you'll have to do this yourself.